# Javascript concatenate array of arrays passed into a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, set

Im passing an array of arrays to a function.  I want to:

1. filter each array for unique values
2. concatenate the filtered arrays into a single array
3. coerce the array into a Set, therefore creating a single iterable object of unique values.

I can't seem to scope the variables within/out of function so that it allows me to use the function with any size array of arrays.  I don't have any affection for anything but the outcome - a single iterable object of the uniques values amongst the array of arrays.

Pseudo code:

```
function getDataForHistogram(shipments, groupKeys) {
    console.log('@getDataForHistogram');
    let uniqueArry = [];
    groupKeys.forEach(groupKey => {
        uniqueArry.concat(shipments.reduce((accumulator, element) => {. //pseudo, I know concat returns an array
            if ((accumulator.indexOf(Math.ceil(element[groupKey])) < 0)) {
                accumulator.push(Math.ceil(element[groupKey]));
            }
            return accumulator;
        },[])
    })
    let uniqueSet = new Set(...uniqueArry);
    let range = {
        min: Math.min(uniqueSet),
        max: Math.max(uniqueSet)
    };
    console.log(uniqueSet);
    console.log(range.min, range.max);
}
```

I'm flummoxed...  The only alternative way that I have thought of is to count the number of arrays and iterate over each three recursively.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the array you are using and show the expected result after the filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for `uniqueArray`. Just add the elements to the `Set`, it will discard duplicates automatically.

```
function getDataForHistogram(shipments, groupKeys) {
  console.log('@getDataForHistogram');
  let uniqueSet = new Set;
  groupKeys.forEach(groupKey =>
    shipments.forEach(element => uniqueSet.add(Math.ceil(element[groupKey])))
  );
  let range = {
    min: Math.min(uniqueSet),
    max: Math.max(uniqueSet)
  };
  console.log(uniqueSet);
  console.log(range.min, range.max);
}
```